# выдаёт ошибку при попытке распаковать архив

Tags: linux, shell, tar

делаю одно задание, там нужно сделать функцию один из этапов которой будет распаковать архив созданную папку
в скрипте у меня написано так:

```
zzgrep () {
    mkdir /home/bondar/temp #создание директории
    tar -xvf "$1" -C /home/bondar/temp/ #распаковка
    find /home/bondar/temp -name "$2" #поиск по второму параметру
    rm -rf /home/bondar/temp #удаление директории
}
zzgrep
```

но при вызове этой функции таким образом

```
/tmp/zzgrep.sh /tmp/arch.tar.gz fold1
```

у меня выводит ошибку:

```
tar: : Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

вроде уже всё проверил, но не работает
помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Вы не передали никакие параметры в функцию `zzgrep`

Comment: путь до архива и имя директории/файла не параметры?

Comment: Это параметры скрипта, а в функцию вы их не передали

Comment: можете подсказать пожалуйста как решить эту проблему